# numitron tube IV-6

Tags: nixie

I have a IV-6 numitron tube, and it requires 25V over each segment. The segments have a common cathode. I thought of putting a BJT transistor, with numitron in collector, until I realized that cathode is common, meaning that when I switch one segment on, everything goes on. I cannot put it in emitter, as then the voltage will be ~4.3V. I have 5V switching logic. How do I approach this problem? I do have a 25V source.

Comment: Use PNP and switch the anodes instead, and NPN to switch the PNPs?

Comment: I have 6 numitrons, 8 segments each, 48 NPN and 48 PNP sounds like a lot

Comment: 96 transistors? Read up on multiplexing

Comment: Never mind the transistors.  Driving each segment separately will require 48 pins from your processor.  Does it have that many IO pins?  If not, then you must mulitiplex.

Comment: yes, if I use I/O expander then yes. However, multiplexing would require higher voltage, 50V as stated in datasheet.

Comment: Multiplexing shouldn't require a higher voltage.  You have a segment driver with 8 transistors.  You have a tube select with 6 transistors.  Supply 25V to all of the segment drivers, and drive the tube select to ground.  14 IO  pins, and whatever transistors it takes to drive the tubes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing the same problem. My approach is to wire each segment to the high voltage supply via a pullup resistor, then switch each segment on or off using a [TPIC6b595](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpic6b595.pdf). The IC provides a sink for high voltages, so when activating the sink for a given segment, the voltage applied to the segment will drop to 0v and the segment will turn off.

This (if I've read correctly) is the same setup as described at the bottom of this [blog post](https://www.electroschematics.com/qa/9741/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a circuit used by a previous pinball company to drive hundred of lamps.
A lamp is the same as a filament numitron tube. Notice the Bridge Rectifier has no capacitor for filtering only a 25 ohm resistor to pull SCR low when no 5 Volt drive voltage is on the gate. Should work to drive a numitron tube as well, with a different supply voltage for the filaments.[image]